# Convergence Criterium

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Consider $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$.

$f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are functions in the form $a(n+b)^{c} + d(n+e)^{f}...$, with $c, f ... \in  \Bbb R$

Let $m$ be the largest exponent in $f(n)$ and $j$ the largest exponent in $g(n)$.

Is it possible to afirm that, if $j-m > 1$, then the infinite series converges?

My ideas was that if $j-m>1$, then there is a second series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$, with $j-m>p>1$ such that $n^p$ will be eventually smaller than $\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}$ as, with $n \to \infty$ , $\frac{g(n)}{f(n)} \to k\times n^{j-m}$ ($k$ being just a constant coefficient), which is greater than $n^p$.

Then,  $\frac{1}{k\times n^{j-m}} < \frac{1}{n^p}$. Since $p>1$, $\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges. By the comparison test, the first series also converges.

Does this procceed?

Thanks!

Edit: just as an example, I came with this when analyzing the convergence of $\frac{\sqrt(k+1)}{k^2-3k+1}$. In this case, $j=2$, $m=1/2$, $j-m = 1,5 > 1$. By my logic, the series would converge, and it does, indeed. I just wanted to know if my logic is valid and can be used in other similar cases.

Comment: This looks fine except for two things: You are using $n$ for two different things, and that giving you non-sense like $n^{n-m}$ which is not a even a polynomial expression. It should be something like $n^{j-m}$.

Comment: Sorry, I will correct this

Comment: Also $\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}\to k \times n^{j-m}$ is incorrect: the expression $a(n) \to b$ is equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty} a(n) = b$, so it makes no sense that the RHS ($b$ in this case) depends on $n$. Your intuition is right, $\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}$ and $k\times n^{j-m}$ are similar for $n$ big, but the correct way to write this is $\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}\sim k \times n^{j-m}$, which has the precise meaning $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n)/f(n)}{k \times n^{j-m}} =1$.

Comment: And just some comments about MathJax: don't use weird characters like ², write the exponents using the proper way: `x^2`. For $\Bbb R$ write `\Bbb R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is fine and this is precisely the theorem known as [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), that is given that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}}{k\, n^{j-m}} =1$$

then $\sum \frac{g(n)}{f(n)}$ behaves like $\sum k\, n^{j-m}$.

The idea is that since eventually we have

$$(1-\varepsilon)\,k\, n^{j-m}\le \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} \le (1+\varepsilon)\,k\, n^{j-m} $$

then we can conclude by direct comparison test that both series converge or both series diverge.